# Optimized way to store and search for strings in a PHP file instead of database

Tags: php

I'm developing a system in WordPress that has many pages; templates; modules. To make the system more organized and easier to grow and manage, I decided to keep all important strings stored at files on some particular subfolders and search for them with a function, but I'm worried that my code and way of storing strings might not be effective and make the system unnecessarily slower.

I decided to save all strings on files called strings within a subfolders separated by parts of the system, like **/inc/strings/{subfolder}/strings.php**.

On those files I've store the strings on switch cases.

```
<?php

switch ($slug) {
    case 'content-approved'   : $string = 'You have approved the content.'; break;
    case 'acess-denied'   : $string = 'You do not have acess to that content'; break;
    // and so on..
 }
```

And I created the following function to search for stored strings

```
<?php

function get_string($local, $slug, $args = null){

    // get the right subfolder
    require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/strings/' . $local . '/strings.php';

    // return the string
    return $string;
}
```

So on the templates and parts of site, I search for strings using the function

```
<body>

 <div class="network-box">
  <h2> <?=get_string('networks', 'content-title');?> </h2>
 </div>

</body>
```

The point is, considering some files might have 20+ strings on a switch case and some templates might search 8+ times for different strings using this function, is this a smart and effective way to store and search for strings, or I'm an idiot that doesn't know what is doing? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've seen things like this, so it's not the end of the world. I would probably suggest a different format, such as JSON or just return a PHP associative array. The benefit is that if later on you _do_ run into problems, these formats will be easier to parse/transform than a switch statement.

Comment: A key to good design is that you're not always going to know what works, and you want changing your mind to be easy/cheap.

Comment: @KarlHill absolutely not what sessions are for.

Comment: @Evert An associative array sounds way better than switch, I'm actually feeling really stupid for not considering it. Haha. But do you think, in terms of performance, working with JSON is better than php associative array or the difference is not that much for small projects to worry about?

Comment: PHP files _used_ to be the fastest because they are cached really well, but regardless it doesn't sound like you are at a scale where this makes any difference.  JSON could be worse if you parse every time you read string.

Comment: Thank you very much. Gonna follow with the arrays for this :D

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this? To use the same texts in a multitude of places, but configure them only once? I am wondering if you would not perhaps be better of using WordPress' built-in translation system. (That can "translate" within a language as well. So even if you used the text `You have approved the content.` directly in your template, but it should be changed to a slightly different phrasing - then you could "translate" that phrase within the English language files to something different.)